# Multiple players for an android game

Tags: android

I am trying to make a game, very simple, kind of a game where you simply have to solve some questions. 
Now I want to make it possible to make multiple players. One way is to make an sql table with players, and just put each score, for each question, for each player in it. 
To know which player was last, I can save it to a table 'currentplayer' or something.

Now I was thinking, isn't this a little bit too much? Is there a easier, or better way of handling this?

Answer (score 0):

Updating an sqlite table during gameplay isn't such a good idea. It's like leaving the fridge for open just cause you'll know you'll be using it in increments over the day. I would make a score keeping object that initializes one for each person playing. Then at the end, you can put it in a database or whatever.

Comment: So at onpause and onstop I write to the db and empty the object? 
I now write immediatelly to my db.. I must say that I didn't experience any timelag or anything... Why is it so much better to use an object?

Comment: I was thinking that you save to database when the game ends. You get a lot more flexibility by using objects I'd think. Plus you don't have the anxiety of frequent transactions. honestly I don't have much better reasons than "it just seems bad". Perhaps someone else could explain better. I used to do what you're talking about. But now I've found it more... "robust" and conventional to use other methods.